# Callback not saving value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback

I am writing some tests for a relatively complicated action that I need to occur when a record is destroyed.

These are my `CheckIn` functions and a `CheckIn` `has_one :weigh_in`:

```
def weight_loss
  prev_ci = CheckIn.joins(:weigh_in)
                   .where(client_id: self.client_id)
                   .where('week < ?', self.week)
                   .where('weigh_ins.current_weight IS NOT NULL')
                   .order('week desc').first()


  return 0 if self.weigh_in.nil? or prev_ci.nil? or prev_ci.weigh_in.nil?
  change = prev_ci.weigh_in.current_weight.to_f - self.weigh_in.current_weight.to_f
  return change.round(2)
end

def prev_ci
    prev_ci = CheckIn.joins(:weigh_in)
                   .where(client_id: self.client_id)
                   .where('week < ?', self.week)
                   .where('weigh_ins.current_weight IS NOT NULL')
                   .order('week desc').first()
  return prev_ci
end

def post_ci
    post_ci = CheckIn.joins(:weigh_in)
                               .where(client_id: self.client_id)
                               .where('week > ?', self.week)
                               .where('weigh_ins.current_weight IS NOT NULL')
                               .order('week desc').first()

    return nil if post_ci.nil? or post_ci.weigh_in.nil?
    return post_ci
end
```

In my `WeighIn` model I have the following callbacks:

```
class WeighIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :check_in

  before_save :add_weightloss
  after_destroy :adjust_weightloss

  def add_weightloss
    self.weightloss = 0
    self.weightloss = self.check_in.weight_loss
  end

  def adjust_weightloss
    post_ci = self.check_in.post_ci

    unless post_ci.nil?
        post_ci.weigh_in.weightloss = 0
        post_ci.weigh_in.weightloss = post_ci.weight_loss

        # Prints the correct value to pass the test (39.7)
        p 6, post_ci.weigh_in
        post_ci.weigh_in.save!
    end
  end
end
```

But my final test (for deletion) still fails:

```
RSpec.describe WeighIn, type: :model do
  it "before_save weigh_in" do
      ci1 = CheckIn.create!(client_id: 1, program_id: 1, week: 1)
      ci2 = CheckIn.create!(client_id: 1, program_id: 1, week: 2)
      ci3 = CheckIn.create!(client_id: 1, program_id: 1, week: 3)
      ci4 = CheckIn.create!(client_id: 1, program_id: 1, week: 4)

      wi1 = WeighIn.create!(check_in_id: ci1.id, client_id: 1, date: Date.today, current_weight: 100)
      wi2 = WeighIn.create!(check_in_id: ci2.id, client_id: 1, date: Date.today, current_weight: 90)
      wi3 = WeighIn.create!(check_in_id: ci4.id, client_id: 1, date: Date.today, current_weight: 70.5)

      # Verifies functionality of before save
      expect(wi1.weightloss).to eq 0
      expect(wi2.weightloss).to eq 10
      expect(wi3.weightloss).to eq 19.5

      # Verifies fucntionality of update
      wi_params = { check_in_id: ci4.id, client_id: 1, date: Date.today, current_weight: 60.3 }
      wi3.update(wi_params)
      expect(wi3.weightloss).to eq 29.7

      # Verifies functionality of destroy
      wi2.destroy

      # Prints incorrect, old value, 29.7
      p 'in test', wi3
      expect(wi3.weightloss).to eq 39.7
    end
end
```

**It seems a though the functions are working properly but the record reverts back or is never saved / updated?**

Comment: Can you try this? `expect(wi3.reload.weightloss).to eq 39.7` to reload the object

Comment: Did you tried to reloading w3?

Comment: ahhh that did it!  Thank you.  I thought I was missing something.

Comment: @TanNguyenNhat If you make it answer I'll accept it

Comment: @JeremyThomas I'm glad it helped! Done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this to reload the object to check for a change?

```
expect(wi3.reload.weightloss).to eq 39.7
```